# Intersecting polar curves r=1+cosθ and r=1-cosθ

Tags: polar-coordinates

The question was asking for the intersection points of $r=1+\cos \theta$ and $r=1-\cos \theta$ with $0≤ \theta ≤2\pi$, but doing:

$1+\cos \theta=1-\cos\theta$

0=2cosθ

0=cosθ

θ=$\frac π2$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Yields an incomplete answer.

When the two curves are graphed a third intersection appears at the pole, but at two separate angles for each graph.

θ=π and θ=0

[image: Red is r=1-cosθ. Blue is r=1+cosθ]

How would I find this intersection point without looking at the graph and tracing the curves?

Answer (score 3):

You need not just solve for $f(\theta) = g(\theta)$, but also solve for $f(\theta) = -g(\pi + \theta)$, to take into account the chance that a point of intersection of this form.

For your example $f = 1+\cos\theta, g = 1-\cos\theta$, so you need to solve for $1+\cos\theta = -1+\cos(\theta+\pi) = -1-\cos\theta$.  This simplifies to $\cos\theta = -1$, so $\theta = \pi$, as desired.

edit: I just realized that you generally need to check the origin as a special case, too, since $r,\theta$ represents the origin whenever $r=0$ no matter the value of $\theta$.

Comment: Is there more reasoning to that extra step? Is it trying to take in account a negative radius?

Comment: Two points $r_1, \theta_1$ and $r_2, \theta_2$  represent the same point on the plane precisely when $r_1 = r_2, \theta_1 = \theta_2$, or when $r_1 = -r_2, \theta_1 = \theta_2 + \pi$, (or  $r_1 = r_2 = 0$ as a special case).

Comment: HoyerSo when checking for intersections I should set both curves equal to each other, check for when they equal 0 and check for

Comment: As long as your functions are $2\pi$-periodic in $\theta$, that should suffice.  If the period is larger, you're going to need to take in to account other symmetries like $r,\theta \sim r, \theta+2\pi$.

Comment: Hi, an instructor says that the origin cannot be considered as an intersection because *the time they pass through origin* is not the same. So do you have a reference OR how to convince her? Thanks.

Comment: @Ninja the distinction here is whether the term "intersection" is taken in the sense of 'which two points on the plane are contained in both of these curves' or 'when do these curves collide'. The latter case is your instructor's, although I would argue that it only really makes sense for curves parameterized over time. Implicitly, using the variable $\theta$ means we are considering polar coordinates, parameterizing the curve with respect to angle as opposed to time.